# Failed to install gem mysql2 on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Tags: ruby, rubygems, mysql2

When I run the `gem install mysql2` command I get the following error message:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
...
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
... 
To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /home/lucivaldo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.4.0/mysql2-0.4.9/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/lucivaldo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.9 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/lucivaldo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.4.0/mysql2-0.4.9/gem_make.out
```

Looking at the log file described at the end of the message I noticed that some library is missing.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install client libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-mysql libmysqlclient-dev
```

Answer (score -1):

Searching here in Stack Overflow itself, I found a solution to another problem similar to the following command, which also solves this problem:

```
sudo apt install libgmp3-dev
```